# Running PHP echo $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; Shows Apache Default Path

Tags: cpanel, apache2, document-root

Trying to get set up and running on a new hosting company after the old one announced they are discontinuing their service at the end of the year, I am having difficulty getting the sites to run. I narrowed it down to Apache's DocumentRoot for each domain showing the Apache default path rather than showing the path to the individual site's file location. In other words, when I run `echo $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` in a test script, it shows the path as */etc/apache2/htdocs* when it should show */home/username/public_html/domain.com*. They seem unable to fix it so can DocumentRoot be changed through cPanel for each domain?

Comment: From the StackOverflow question [Setting PHP Document Root on webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017381/setting-php-document-root-on-webserver) this happens when your host is using `mod_vhost_alias` under Apache 2.2.

Comment: Thank you and the question is how to fix it. Does that mean that they need to disable mod_vhost_alias and is that something that can be done in cPanel?

Comment: The StackOverflow question has two ways your host could fix it.   There is a PHP script they could add to correctly set the document root everywhere.   They could also upgrade to Apache 2.4 where the problem is fixed.    As for fixing it yourself, could you edit all the PHP files and replace the `$_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` with something else?

Comment: Thank you. None of those things are options, unfortunately, and I just got word that the hosting company (Hostgator) will not fix it so I am cancelling the service and going elsewhere.

Comment: Have you been able to confirm what Apache version you have at Hostgator? Apache 2.2 was EOL over 2 years ago and [Hostgator state they use Apache 2.4 on all shared servers](https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/what-software-and-program-versions-does-hostgator-offer)? What service are you using? A "shared account" with multi-domain support?

Comment: It was a reseller account as I have many sites and that is the easiest way for me to host them all, short of doing so myself (which I may try at some point). I have only one that is an actual resale and it's for a friend. I don't know that Hostgator uses Apache 2.4 or something else but I do know that the setting in question is not properly set to be of any use and they refuse to change it.

Comment: "None of those things are options" - You should be able to set the `auto_prepend_file` within cPanel (PHP Selector > Options) in order to "correct" the DOCUMENT_ROOT. If you have a reseller account then you can do this independently for each domain/site. You can also set this in `.htaccess` or `.user.ini` (depending on your config). You don't _need_ to edit the main server config, as the linked SO question suggests.